# Как сделать чтоб отпрвялся запрос через определенный интервал ??7

Tags: java, android

Есть метод `myMethod();` надо его запускать через определенное время допустим 45-60 секунд ,пытался сделать через

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   myMethod();
                }
            }, 15000, 40000); /
```

Таймер не точный и порой интервал спускается до 2 секунд .Если какие либо другие таймеры или выход какой нибудь ,был-бы весьма благодарен .

Comment: Скорей всего проблема в вашем коде, либо во всяких ограничителях типа doze mode. У меня за 20 минут погрешность от запуска к запуску не выходила за несколько сотых секунды.

Comment: @temq а это может быть утечкой паяти?т

Comment: как мне найти проблему???

Comment: Нет, причём тут утечка? Даже если она и есть, то она врядли может повлиять на запуск задачи.

Comment: Смотрите свой код, смотрите на каком устройстве это происходит, в каких ситуациях,  какие на этом  устройстве есть увеличители жизни батареи, например doze mode на android 6+.

Comment: @temq у меня запуск происходит в locationChanged может при изменении локации он зановзапускает интервл и они накладываются????может такое быть ?

Comment: и место запроса я получаю ддос атаку на свйже сервер?)

Comment: Конечно. Грубо говоря сколь раз locationChanged вызвался, столько задач на ожидание и запустилось, отсюда и ощущение что таймер работает не верно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать `CountDownTimer`, только не создавать каждый раз новый, а запускать или отменять используя методы `start()` и `cancel()` соответственно